# What is a good word when someone wants to "bury" and "ignore" an idea, like in politics or science?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I was giving a talk about genetics and education, and nobody wanted to hear this. I was thinking *obfuscate* was the correct word for what they were doing, but it means ‘to make unclear’, not ‘to suppress and ignore it’. Any good words for when you attempt to suppress and ignore something?

Comment: I'd prolly say *they're being **dismissive**...*, but it's not a verb.

Answer (score 4):

If you think that they heard and understood, but lacked interest or motivation to do anything about what you were saying, you might say they were "*dismissive*" or "*indifferent*".

If you think that they deliberately ignored unpleasant, or uncomfortable facts for their own convenience, you could say they *ignored* or '*turned a blind eye*' to what you said. You could also say that they '*swept it aside*' or '*looked the other way*'.

If you think that they denied what you said to themselves because they didn't want to believe it was true, you might say are '*in denial*', '*hearing what they want to hear*', or '*lying to themselves*'.